# Java 8 - Constructor Reference - The type Select does not define Select(DataObj) that is applicable here"

Tags: java, java-8

I defined one `FunctionalInterface` as below:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BaseAction {
   public void execute(final DataObj dataObj) throws Exception;
}
```

Then, a class implementing the same as follows:

```
public class Select implements BaseAction{

    @Override
    public void execute(final DataObj dataObj) {
        //some operations on dataObj here..
    }
}
```

And when I tried instantiating the class `Select` using syntax prior to `Java 8`, compiles for me, as follows:

```
public BaseAction getAction(final String action) {      
    switch (action) {
          case "SELECT": return new Select(); //Works
     }
        return null;
}
```

But, when I tried instantiating it using `Java 8` syntax, IDE starts complaining me **`"The type Select does not define Select(DataObj) that is applicable here"`**,

```
public BaseAction getAction(final String action) {
    switch (action) {
         case "SELECT": return Select::new; //Compile error here..
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: you are returning a `constructor reference`, and not an instance of `BaseAction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're using is not "the Java 8 syntax for creating an object". You're using a reference to the constructor, so in a way the difference between your two pieces of code is the same as between

`someObject.toString()`

and

`someObject.toString`

The first one instantiates a new object, the second one points to the thing used to instantiate the new object, but doesn't call it <sub>(the more precise analogy would be to `someObject::toString`, by the way)</sub>.

If all you want to do is to instantiate a `Select` object, then just keep using the "old" code, it's exactly how you'll do it in Java 8.

The new syntax is useful if you want to pass the specific constructor to use to some piece of code that wants to be agnostic to which constructor/type is used.

You could do something like that:

```
public void executeBaseAction(DataObject data, Supplier<BaseAction> baseActionSupplier) {
    BaseAction action = baseActionSupplier.get();
    action.execute(data);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
executeBaseAction(data, Select::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method reference `Select::new` is a reference to a constructor, and it doesn't match the required functional interface signature, taking a `DataObj` parameter and returning `void`.

You'll need a `Select` reference to create the method reference, but it must refer to the `execute` method.  This should work:

```
case "SELECT": return new Select()::execute;
```

As you've noted, `return new Select();` works, and it's less verbose.  I would still use this, but the method reference above should work.

Comment: `new Select()::execute` is exactly equivalent to `new Select()` in  this case, since `Select` already implements the desired interface.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: it is not *exactly* equivalent. `new Select()` produces an instance of type `Select` that allows using specific methods of class `Select`. Applying `::execute` to it produces an instance of type `BaseAction` that can not get cast back to `Select`.